# Run "npm install" as if package was not in workspace

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on an [NPM workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) node project. To deploy one of the workspace's packages, I would like to run `npm install` and obtain a `node_modules` directory as a subdirectory of that package such that the package becomes self-contained.

Consider the directory structure below:

```
node_modules
packages
  ├ cloud-app
  │  ├ src
  │  └ package.json
  ├ helpers
  │  ├ src
  │  └ package.json
  ├ business-logic
  │  ├ src
  └  └ package.json
package.json
```

Just one deduplicated `node_modules` is excellent for development in a monorepo. But to deploy the `cloud-app` package, I need the structure to look like this:

```
packages
  ├ cloud-app
  │  ├ node_modules
  │  ├ src
  │  └ package.json
  ├ helpers
  │  ├ src
  │  └ package.json
  ├ business-logic
  │  ├ src
  └  └ package.json
package.json
```

Then, I could upload the `cloud-app` directory as usual without exposing my NPM workspace to the vendor's (incompatible) CD pipeline.

Is this possible at all? What would be the correct command or procedure here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not find a standard way to achieve this, there is a slightly hacky way that worked for me:

Copying the `node_modules` directory allows the package to act as a stand-alone module. However, there is one caveat: The `node_modules` directory contains a symlink for each package in the workspace. Thus, a loop begins when it is copied into a package and when symlinks are followed. To prevent this, we first have to delete our package. Therefore, a deploy script could look something like this:

```bash
rm ./node_modules/cloud-app
cp -rL ./node_modules ./cloud-app/node_modules
# deploy cloud-app here
```

I thought of this while formulating the above question but would still be delighted to know whether there is any canonical, supported way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work. Try the workspaces argument:

```
cd <my_project_root>
npm i --workspaces=false
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install#workspaces

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. The `node_modules` folder of the package was populated with all of the package's direct dependencies and a `package-lock.json` file was generated in the package folder.